# jQuery UI Dialog with form fields - iOS bug/issue

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Experiencing an issue with jQuery UI Dialog, form fields and iOS. This issue is not specific to my code, but can also be seen at:

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

To recreate the issue (in iOS - I'm using an iPad):

- focus into field in the dialog
- input characters
- scroll the window behind
- tap into the same field (even though it already has focus)
- "select/select all" tooltip may come up, if it does scroll again
- try typing additional characters, and you will be unable to

Seems to be a bug? Anyone resolved for this issue?

**Edit**

issue can be recreated by tapping into any field within a dialog that already has focus, without scrolling.

**Edit #2**

seems to only be an issue with a combination of dialogs, form fields and iframes - the demo from jQuery UI is in an iframe. If you go to the iframe src url, the issue is not present. In my own code, we have an iframe inside of the dialog with form fields, which also presents the same issue.

**Edit #3**
Issue occurs in Chrome on iOS as well. iOS versions 6 & 7

Additional details. In some scenarios of this behavior, you cannot add characters, but you can delete characters.

Comment: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9737